# Merging to dataset together according to key

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have two datasets stored in a cell array and a double array, respectively. The design of the two arrays is:

Array 1 (name: **res**) (double) is composed of two columns; a unique id column and a data column.

[image]

Array 2 (name: **config**) (cell array) contains 3 column cells, each with a string inside. The last cell in the array contains a id double integer matching the id's in Array 1. The double integer in the cell array is converted to a double when necessary.

[image]

I want to merge the two datasets in order to have the 3 cells in the cell array AND the result column in Array 1 in one common cell array. How do I do this?

I have the following code. The code does not return the correct order of the results.

```
function resMat = buildResultMatrix(res, config)

resMat = {};

count = 1;

count_max = size(res,1)/130;

for i = 1 : size(res,1)
   for j = 1 : size(res,1)
       if isequal(res(i),str2double(config{j,3}))
           if i == 1
               resMat(end+1,:) = {config{j,:} res(j,2:end)};
           else
               if count == 1
                   resMat(end+1,:) = {config{j,:} res(j,2:end)};
               elseif count == count_max
                   resMat(end+1,:) = {config{j,:} res(j,2:end)};
               else
                   resMat(end+1,:) = {config{j,:} res(j,2:end)};
               end
               count = count + 1;
            end
        end
    end
    count = 1;
end
end
```

Comment: Using the matlab debugger may help you to localise your problem.

Comment: I have spend two days now in company with the debugger, so I'm lost..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the id in `config` to numbers:

```
config(:,3) = num2cell(str2double(config(:,3)));
```

Then run this:

```
res = sortrows(res,1);
config(:,4) = num2cell(res(cell2mat(config(:,3)),2))
```

this will put the data from `res` in the 4th column in `config` in the row with the same id.

Comment: I get the following warning: Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in cell2mat (line 83)
            m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});

Comment: What do you get when you run `size(config(:,3))`? Are all cells in the last column of config contain only one number (the id)?

Comment: size(config(:,3)) yields 390 and 1. Yes, the last column of config only contains one number (double), so the column contains a number corresponding to the id number of res - but the numbers are not in order

Comment: Try to run only `cell2mat(config(:,3))`, to see if this cause the problem. If so then type `config{1,3}` and see what type of answer do you get (is the value appears within `[  ]`).

Comment: Note that this method only works when you use all your ids, i.e. you do not skip any integer value as unique id. This solutions assumes that the row indexes in the sorted `res` matrix corresponds with the unique id.

Comment: `cell2mat(config(:,3))` causes the problem and `config{1, 3}` gives ans =

    '123'. No data is skipped and the sorted row indexes corresponds with the unique id. Note, that the config unique id is not sorted.

Comment: @MikaelKP the `config` id shouldn't be sorted. But you have strings, not doubles in the cells. I'll edit my answer for that.